# ARM WACK errors

Tags: windows-runtime, arm, bing-maps

When check my app for `WACK`.
On `ARM` platform I have several error:

```
- This app failed the performance test in the Windows App Certification
   Kit
 - This app failed the Direct3D test in the Windows App    Certification
   Kit
```

App using `Bing.Maps`. What is the problem?

Comment: the WACK log does provide links to MSDN documentation about common causes for failures.  Have you seen those?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue was with Visual Studio updates. When I update to the latest version the problem disappeared.